# golang NOT operation for byte representation of number

Tags: go, math, byte

I have an `int64` number. How do i use NOT operation in golang for this num?

Example

```
78 is 1001110 
!78 is 0110001
```

Comment: Use the `^` operator and masking.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans yes